# php mysql get variable in config.php and use it in another php file * new one

Tags: php, mysql

so earlier I've posted something like this already but I have a different code now for the config.php which

```
<?php 

define('BASE_PATH', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));
define('APP_FOLDER','simpleadmin');

require_once BASE_PATH.'/lib/MysqliDb.php';
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "gm";
// create connection object

$db =new MysqliDb($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);?>
```

when i require in once in another php file... it gives this error

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method MysqliDb::real_escape_string() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Grove\cus_register.php on line 11
```

this is the file where I'm requiring it

```
<?php
require_once './config/config.php';
$msg = "";
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {      

    $f_name = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['f_name']);
^ in the line of code above is where the error comes
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please do not include images of code, include the code as text. Code can be formatted by clicking on the 'Code sample' link above the editor area.

Comment: @kiko software thank you for the info, there's the code

Comment: Set there info in session

Comment: In the code you have given `$_SESSION['f_name']` is never defined, so it doesn't exist, hence the error.

Comment: the question should be marked as solved by accepting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use  `session_start();` at the beginnig of both .php files to share session variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
function get_name($email_add) {

   global $conn;

   $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_customers WHERE email_add = '$email_add'";

   $result = $conn->query($sql);

   $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

   return $row["id"];//try to use id instead of f_name

}
```

By returning id on your query you can now select any column under tbl_customers. You just need to use where clause whenever you query by their respective id.

and also if you're using session make sure you put `session_start();` at after `<?php` open tag.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the php file for make the connection, you can use the [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) function for use this $conn where you want, for exaple:

Index File:

```
<?php
     include 'Config.php'; //The file with that code
     //Code with $conn variable
?>
```

Is it what you need?

Comment: I use this technique when i make a website in php, I make db.php file with the connection and then i include this in all pages where i need that. Another example is for session, if you make start the session inside db.php (cheking first if the session is not pre-start), so I don't need to change that piece of code if i change db.

Comment: yes this is the file for connection, what I need is the variable $conn for me to be able to use it for the code mysqli_query

Comment: Yes, but how you call that file?
How you call the file when the user connect to your website?

Comment: I've used the code you posted. It worked! Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome.
Remember that if you use this method with a php page that take or view something important, e.g. a page only for the admin, you need to use some protection, like a if($_SESSION['admin']==true) if you use session or if this page is always include you can use [htaccess](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php)